# autocomplete suggestion list in iOS with bluetooth keyboard support

Tags: ios, list, autocomplete

I want functionality similar to `MFMailComposeViewController` in which when user types email address, popup is shown which is controlled by **Bluetooth keyboard** using up & down arrow keys.

How one can implement similar one for `UITextview` ?

-Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement autocomplete, then a good tutorial is available at the Ray Wenderlich blog http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

I think this is not related to the bluetooth keyboard. It may add a few keys that are not available in the virtual keyboard. You will need to handle the up and down keys in code to achieve the same functionality.